# Data Atual no Campo @Html.EditorFor() Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Amigo quero que o campo venha pro padrão já preenchido sem a necessidade do usuário colocar a data

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como colocar data atual no campo por padrão

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataAbate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

**Classe**

```
public class Sequencia
{
    [Key]
    public int SequenciaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data da Sequencia")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataSequencia { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
using GerenciamentoDeQuartos.Classes;
using GerenciamentoDeQuartos.Models;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GerenciamentoDeQuartos.Controllers
{
    public class SequenciasController : Controller
    {
        private GerenciamentoDeQuartosContext db = new GerenciamentoDeQuartosContext();

        // GET: Sequencias
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Sequencias.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Sequencias/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Sequencia sequencia = db.Sequencias.Find(id);
            if (sequencia == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(sequencia);
        }

        // GET: Sequencias/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.LadoA = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetTipoLado(), "TipoLadoId", "Nome");
            ViewBag.CamaraLadoA = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetCamara(), "CamaraId", "Nome");

            ViewBag.LadoB = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetTipoLado(), "TipoLadoId", "Nome");
            ViewBag.CamaraLadoB = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetCamara(), "CamaraId", "Nome");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Sequencias/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Sequencia sequencia)
        {            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Sequencias.Add(sequencia);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(sequencia);
        }

        // GET: Sequencias/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Sequencia sequencia = db.Sequencias.Find(id);
            if (sequencia == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.LadoA = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetTipoLado(), "TipoLadoId", "Nome", sequencia.LadoA);
            ViewBag.CamaraLadoA = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetCamara(), "CamaraId", "Nome", sequencia.CamaraLadoA);

            ViewBag.LadoB = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetTipoLado(), "TipoLadoId", "Nome", sequencia.LadoB);
            ViewBag.CamaraLadoB = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetCamara(), "CamaraId", "Nome", sequencia.CamaraLadoB);

            return View(sequencia);
        }

        // POST: Sequencias/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Sequencia sequencia)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(sequencia).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(sequencia);
        }

        // GET: Sequencias/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Sequencia sequencia = db.Sequencias.Find(id);
            if (sequencia == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(sequencia);
        }

        // POST: Sequencias/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Sequencia sequencia = db.Sequencias.Find(id);
            db.Sequencias.Remove(sequencia);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Problema resolvido com esta solução do link abaixo:

[PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO COM O TUTORIAL DESTE LINK](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-atributo-datatype-date-nao-exibe-valor-view/)

Comment: dentro do controle vc pode passar o DateTime.now(), caso tenha duvida post seu controller que eu posso escreve uma solucao

Comment: @HudsonPH Acabei de colocar o controller, para você poder escrever a solução.

Answer (score 1):

O Melhor local para você fazer a correção é no construtor do seu modelo.

```
public class Sequencia
{
    public Sequencia()
    {
       DataSequencia = DateTime.now();
    }

    [Key]
    public int SequenciaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data da Sequencia")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataSequencia { get; set; }
}
```

Mas a uma discrepância com seu modelo e sua View. 
A sua view acessa o campo *DataAbate* =>  `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataAbate,` e seu modelo não tem esse campo, reveja isso.

Outra coisa que deve ser observada, é que o seu o retorna da sua view no seu primeiro create não é uma View tipada. Altere para retorna com o tipo correto.

Ou seja

```
 Sequencia sequencia = new Sequencia();
 return View(sequencia);
```

Comment: Tudo bem isto que você postou é para sempre salvar com a data atual, mas o que estou querendo é quando entro na View Create ou Edit o campo já venha preenchido com a Data Atual sem a necessidade do usuário preencher e isto não acontece, o campo sempre vem sem valor.

Comment: Alguma vez já foi salvo no banco ?  quando você faz seu db.Sequencias.Find(id); ela vem com o seu campo data com uma data?

Comment: mesmo salvando a data e quando vou para a tela de editar o campo data não volta com o valor preenchido, sempre tenho que colocar a data novamente.

Comment: Fiz o que você me pediu logo acima, criei o construtor fiz a tipagem de minha view Create para retornar a data no campo, mas nada acontece, no construtor coloque para inicializar outros campos e nos outros são preenchidos.

Answer (score 1):

voce so precisa carregar a data no model para pode passar para view `sequencia.DataSequencia = DateTime.now();`

```
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);                    
            }
            Sequencia sequencia = db.Sequencias.Find(id);
            if (sequencia == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            // aqui
            sequencia.DataSequencia = DateTime.now();
            return View(sequencia);
        }
```